# If I need a data structure with random access, is Vector my only good choice?

Tags: haskell

And if there are other good choices, why isn't there a typeclass yet that has all the common traits of random access? Then Vector and other random access data structures would have instances of that typeclass.

Comment: I guess "the common traits of random access" can not be defined precisely, so it would be hard to reach consensus among all the library contributors. You can propose your own class, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `Vector` is not your only "good" choice, depending on what you mean by "good".  For example, `Array` is a similar data structure with a slightly more cumbersome API, but it also allows a richer set of choices for the indexing set and differs in implementation details in ways that might be helpful in some cases (e.g., an `Array` of `Bool`s is a bitmap, while a `Vector` of `Bool`s uses one byte per element).

Also, if there is much adding and removing of elements on the ends, then the `Seq` type from `Data.Sequence` might be a good choice (though its random access performance varies from `O(1)` at the ends to `O(log n)` in the middle, roughly speaking).

It's hard to say definitely why there is no standard library typeclass for a random access API, but note that Haskell typically does not have data structure API typeclasses of this level of specificity in the standard library.  There are no standard typeclasses for the base `Map` and `Set` data structures APIs either, for example, even though these would also apply to the various hash-based maps and sets that are available.

The standard library typeclasses that *are* available are typically higher-level abstractions, like `Foldable` and `Traversable`.

However, the `lens` package provides a collection of indexed typeclass abstractions, so for example there are `Ixed` instances for `Vector`, `Array`, and `Seq` such that:

```
v ^? ix 2
```

gets you `Just` the element with index 2, if `v` is any one of the above types (or a list or a host of other indexable collections).  The possible downside of using these typeclasses is that you kind of have to buy into the whole `lens` ecosystem and its syntactic approach to use them effectively.

As an alternative, for a particular application, it's often a reasonable approach to write application-specific typeclasses that encapsulate the operations performed on key data structures and then implement the data structures as instances of those typeclasses.  This can realize many of the benefits of the generic typeclasses you're imagining, but can be more flexible than pre-fabricated typeclasses and instances without being that much more work to implement.

Comment: +1 to final paragraph.  Sometimes when doing this miraculous new structures arise that allow me to generalize my program beyond what I originally imagined.

Comment: @luqui & @KABuhr: Let's say I have written a function that uses vectors. Let's say the function uses only the `length` and `(!)` (indexing) functions. Are you guys advocating that I put those two functions into a separate typeclass `HasLengthAndIndexing`? Or maybe even two typeclasses `WithLength` and `Indexable`? That's general as hell. But I guess one can take things too far. Can you add some thoughts on this?

Comment: I had in mind application-specific typeclasses containing coherent sets of operations, not per-function typeclasses containing minimum required sets of operations.  (The latter approach is useful in some situations, but it wasn't what I was suggesting.)  Taking a step back, I would advocate against premature abstraction for most Haskell programming.  If you have a function that uses vectors, I'd suggest writing it to use `Vector`s.  If you later discover it would be helpful to generalize, then refactor it to use a `RandomAccess` typeclass tailored to your program.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr yes!  Haskell programming is a conversational art.  Write some, refactor & abstract when you notice a pattern (or when it is aesthetically pleasing), write more, abstract more -- uncover the balance like an archaeologist rather than egoistically willing the optimal design into existence.